# Two questions about Dispose() and destructors in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, destructor, finalizer

I have a question about how to use `Dispose()` and destructors. Reading some articles and the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx), this seems to be the recommended way of implementing `Dispose()` and destructors.

But I have two questions about this implementation, that you can read below:

```
class Testing : IDisposable
{
    bool _disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed) // only dispose once!
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Not in destructor, OK to reference other objects
            }
            // perform cleanup for this object
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        // tell the GC not to finalize
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~Testing()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

### GC.SupressFinalize(this) on Dispose()

When the programmer uses `using` or calls Dispose() explicity, our class is calling to `GC.SupressFinalize(this)`. My question here is:

- What this exactly means? Will the object be collected but without calling the destructor?. I guess that the anwswer is yes since [destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are converted by the framework to a Finalize() call, but I'm not sure.

### Finalizing without a Dispose() call

Suppose that the GC is going to clean our object but the programmer did not call `Dispose()`

- Why don't we dispose resource at this point? In other words, why can't we free resources on destructor?
- What code must be executed in the if inside, and what outside?

  ```
  if (!_disposed) // only dispose once!
  {
     if (disposing)
     {
         //What should I do here and why?
     }
     // And what here and why?
  }
  ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK this pattern is outdated. For unmanaged resources you usually should use a `SafeHandle` and managed resources usually don't require a finalizer.

Comment: @codein, you're right but is there a canonical write-up on MSDN somewhere?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Could you provide some literature about it, please?

Comment: Personally I subscribe to the school of thought that says that the only thing a (non critical) finalizer should do is notifying the programmer of a potential bug.

Comment: I have no canonical reference at hand, but there are several blogs describing either the problems with normal finalization(in particular it doesn't always execute and is hard to code) or the advantages of safehandles/critical finalization http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396335.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/20/77460.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh21e17c(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @HenkHolterman Its not on the MSDN, but it is written by Stephen Cleary "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### 1. What does SuppressFinalize do?

It unregisters the object from the finalizer list, ie when the GC later collects the object it will ignore the presence of the destructor. This is a big gain in performance since the destructor would otherwise require the object's collection, and that of everything it references, to be delayed.

#### 2. Why don't we dispose [managed] resource at this point? In other words, why can't we free [managed] resources on destructor?

You could, but it is certain to be pointless: the object you're in has become unreachable so all those owned managed resources are unreachable too. They will  be Finalized and collected by the GC in the same run and calling Dispose() on them is unnecessary but not totally without risk or cost.

**2a What code must be executed in the if inside, and what outside?**

Inside the `if(disposing)`, call  `_myField.Dispose()`

In other words, Dispose of **managed** resources (objects with a Dispose)

Outside, call code to cleanup (close) **unmanaged** resources, like `Win32API.Close(_myHandle)`.

Note that when you don't have unmanaged resources, as will usually be the case (look up SafeHandle), you don't need a destructor and therefore no SuppressFinalize.

And that makes that the complete (official) implementation of this pattern is only needed because of the possibility that Test is inherited from.
Note that the `Dispose(bool)` is protected. When you declare your class Testing to be `sealed`, it is totally safe and conforming to omit the `~Testing()`.

Comment: @Henk: After your edit about 2a: Than means that unmanaged resources are always cleaned even the programmer forgot call dispose?

Comment: -1 That's incorrect. You can *not* dispose resources in the finaliser. The references may be invalid, so you can't touch them.

Comment: @Guffa: A reference cannot become invalid as long as you hold it. Type-safety holds up all the way to the Finalize fase. It is just tricky: myField could already have been Disposed (but not collected!). Dispose() on a Disposed object _should_ be safe.

Comment: @Guffa: I think Henk is rigth, because he means dispose managed objects inside the `disposing` block, and this is not the finalizer, is the `Dispose()` call made by the programmer.

Comment: "Than means that unmanaged resources are always cleaned even the programmer forgot call dispose?" No, only if the finalizer happens to run. There are several scenarios where it doesn't run. In particular on forced app-domain unload. This causes problems in multi AppDomain applications.

Comment: Henk is right but... it's worth emphasising again that by referencing a managed `IDisposable` resource in your finaliser you could be artificially keeping it alive longer than necessary. If you didn't reference it in the finaliser then the GC would be free to collect it (and call its fallback finaliser, if it has one) as soon as it's no longer required. There's no need to dispose of managed `IDisposable` resources in your finaliser: if those resources need any fallback finalisation then they should handle it themselves internally.

Comment: @Daniel, "...always cleaned even the programmer forgot call dispose?" Usually yes, with some (rare) exceptions noted by  CodeInChaos . But 'forgetting' to Dispose() is always (very) inefficient, and it could lead to failure.

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba: If he means that, he certainly expressed himself very badly, as he is answering the point about disposing from the finaliser. I don't see the point of explaining what you can do when disposing as an answer to what you can do when finalising.

Comment: @Guffa: I was answering about an `if()` statement that is called in both the Finalizer _and_ the Dispose() ... What/when was the core of the question, but maybe I read is as badly as I express myself.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: If you were, you truely express yourself badly. It clearly looks like you were answering the question "why can't we free resources on destructor?", as the answer follows the headline, and takes the form of a direct answer to it.

Comment: @Guffa, right, you have to refer back to the question to know that is specifically ("at this point") about managed resources.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: You are missing the point completely. It's still a question about what you can do in the finaliser.

Comment: @Guffa, Yes, and I answered that: You _can_ but _should not_ call Dispose() on an owned object. We seem to disagree about the _can_.

Answer (score 2):

*First part:*

When `GC.SupressFinalize(this)` is called, GC is informed that the object has already freed its resources and it can be garbage-collected as any other object. And yes, finalization and "destructors" are the same thing in .NET.

*Second part:*

Finalization is done by a separate thread and we have no control on time and order of finalization, so we don't know whether any other objects are still available or are already finalized. For this reason, you can't reference other object outside the `disposing` block.

Comment: FYI, after the system determines that some objects are eligible for finalization, all such objects, and all objects to which they hold direct or indirect references, will become "live" until such time as the finalizers actually run.  If finalizable object X holds the only existing reference to finalizable object Y, and nothing holds a reference to X, then when X.Finalize() runs, object Y may or may not have had its Finalize() routine run, but object Y is guaranteed to still exist.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the time when an object which owns `IDisposable` resources is finalized, at least one of the following statements will apply to each of those resources:

1. It has already been finalized, in which case no cleanup is necessary.
2. Its finalizer hasn't yet run, but is scheduled to do so, in which case no cleanup is necessary.
3. It can only be cleaned up within a particular thread (which isn't the finalizer thread), in which case the finalizer thread must not try to clean it up.
4. It may still be in use by someone else, in which case the finalizer thread must not try to clean it up.

In some of the rare circumstances where none of the above apply, cleanup within the finalizer might be appropriate, but one shouldn't even consider it unless one has first examined the above four possibilities.